# Can't query data from multiple MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-databases

I have a bit of a problem when connecting to multiple tables, please see the code below:

```
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/init.php';

$vps = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM vp WHERE vp_id = 1");

foreach($vps->results() as $vp){
    $name = escape($vp->name);
}

$vpSlides = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM vp_ss WHERE vp_id = 1 ORDER BY vp_ss_order ASC");

//$vpDays = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM vp_itinerary WHERE vp_id = 1 ORDER BY day ASC");
?>
```

This works fine, I can use the data inside the HTML in my page, but I lose the data as soon as I uncomment this line:

```
//$vpDays = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM vp_itinerary WHERE vp_id = 1 ORDER BY day ASC");
```

`$vpSlides` data is gone but `var_dump` still shows everything.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Can we see the DB class?

Comment: please provide the var_dump you mention.